# Spim Syntax Parser Error

Tags: mips, quicksort, spim, pcspim

I have been working on this translation from HLL to MIPS AL for awhile now and I cannot figure out why I'm getting these syntax errors. I'll post the HLL I'm translating from and what is hopefully my near complete MIPS AL code.

HLL:
[image]

My Current MIPS AL:

```
    .data
array:  .word   8, 2, 7, 10, 5, 6, 3, 4, 9, 3, 1
n:  .word   11

    .text
    .globl main
main:
    la  $a0, array      # array
    li  $a1, 0          # 0
    addi    $a2, $a1, -1        # n-1
    jal     quickSort

    li  $v0, 10
    syscall

quickSort:
    addi    $sp, $sp, -20
    sw  $ra, 4($sp)
    sw  $s0, 8($sp)
    sw  $s1, 12($sp)
    sw  $s2, 16($sp)
    sw  $s3, 20($sp)

    move    $s0, $a0        # array
    move    $s1, $a1        # low from 0
    move    $s2, $a2        # high from n-1
    move    $a3, $v0        # result from partition into $a3


if_init:    

if_compare:
    bge $a1, $a2, end_if
    jal     partition       # pivotPostion = partition(array, low, high)

    move    $s3, $a3        # saves $a3 (results of partition) to s register 3

    lw  $a0, $s0        # Reloading array before first recursive call
    lw  $a1, $s1        # Reloading low before first recursive call
    addi    $a2, $s3, -1        # reloading pivotPosition - 1 before first recursive call
    jal quickSort

    lw  $a0, $s0        # reloading array before second recursive call
    addi    $a1, $s1, 1     # reloading pivotPosition + 1 before second recursive call
    lw  $a2, $s2        # reloading high before second recurvise call
    jal     quickSort

end_if:

end_quickSort:

    lw  $ra, 4($sp)
    lw  $s0, 8($sp)
    lw  $s1, 12($sp)
    lw  $s2, 16($sp)
    lw  $s3, 20($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 20

swap:
    lw  $t0, 0($a0)     # array[left] into $t0
    lw  $t1, 0($a1)     # array[right] into $t1

    sw  $t0, 0($a1)         
    sw  $t1, 0($a0)

    jr  $ra 

end_swap:

partition:

    addi    $sp, $sp, -28
    sw  $ra, 4($sp)
    sw  $s0, 8($sp)
    sw  $s1, 12($sp)
    sw  $s2, 16($sp)
    sw  $s3, 20($sp)
    sw  $s4, 24($sp)
    sw  $s5, 28($sp)

    move    $s0, $a0    # array from main = array
    move    $s1, $a1    # low from 0 in main = left
    move    $s2, $a2    # high from n-1 in main = high

    mul $t0, $s1, 4 
    add $t0, $t0, $s0
    lw  $s3, 0($t0) # array[left] into $s3

    mul $t1, $s2, 4
    add $t1, $t1, $s0
    lw  $s4, 0($t1) #array [right] into $s4

    mul $t2, $s1, 4
    add $t2, $t2, $s0
    lw  $s5, 0($t2) # array[low] = pivot into $s5

while_0:
    bge $s1, $s2, end_while_0

while_1:
    ble $s4, $s3, end_while_1

    addi    $t3, $s2, -1    # right - 1
    sw  $s2, $t3    # right = right - 1

end_while_1:

while_2:
    bge $s1, $s2, end_while_2
    bgt $s3, $s5, end_while_2

    addi    $t4, $s1, -1    # left - 1
    sw  $s1, $t4    # left = left - 1

end_while_2:

if_init:

if_compare:
    bge $s1, $s2, end_if

    sw  $a0, $s3    # array[left] into $a0 for swap
    sw  $a1, $s4    # array[right] into $a1 for swap
    jal swap

end_if:

end_while_0:
    lw  $t5, $s4
    lw  $t6, $s5
    sw  $s5, $t5    # array[low] = array[right]
    sw  $s4, $t6    # array[right] = pivot

    sw  $v0, $s2

end_partition:

    lw  $ra, 4($sp)
    lw  $s0, 8($sp)
    lw  $s1, 12($sp)
    lw  $s2, 16($sp)
    lw  $s3, 20($sp)
    lw  $s4, 24($sp)
    lw  $s5, 28($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 28

    jr  $ra
```

Comment: _"I'm getting these syntax errors"_ **Which** syntax errors?

Comment: Sorry, a parser syntax error on line 38:

    lw   $a0, $s0        #Reloading array before first recursive call

Comment: Well, the second operand is incorrect. If you want to load from memory the second operand should be in parentheses, i.e. `($s0)`. If you just wanted to copy the value of the register you should use `move` instead of `lw`.